# Google Chrome error 159 after upgrade to 22.04 and Google Chrome out of date

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, google-chrome

Before I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 I was being asked to update google chrome. The chrome was 90.0.4430.93. In fact the update requests may have also occurred in 18.04. In 20.04 google chrome worked. In 22.04 chrome it also asks to reinstall chrome but when I click on the reinstall button it repeats the error code 159 on the screen. To be clear Chrome does come up but I can not get anything to display. My Firefox does work with Google.